# How get elements which are between two of the same selector class

Tags: javascript

I need get elements which are between two of the same css selector class.

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div class='active'></div>
    <div></div> // need this
    <div></div> // need this
    <div class='active'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to set the style for elements between active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will you only ever be dealing with two, identical classes on a page? If so, then (in the very specific example given) you could use something along the lines of:

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".active").nextElementSibling;

while ( !( el.classList.contains( "active" ) ) ) {

  // opt 1 - add a class that can be used to add style
  el.classList.add("custom-class");
  
  // opt 2 - use the JS DOM API to directly update element styles
  el.style.color = "yellow";
  
  // go to the next element in the DOM
  el = el.nextElementSibling;
  
};
```

```css
/* Demo style */
.custom-class{
    background: pink;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div></div>
<div class='active'></div>
<div>// need this</div> 
<div>// need this</div> 
<div class='active'></div>
</div>
```

**Edit** Slight tweak to above code based on additional information.

You can add a custom class, or update the style via the JavaScript DOM API.

Comment: Are you specifically restricted to this HTML markup?  If not, please clarify what your goal is.  It is likely there is a better solution for your needs, but we can't help unless we understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've just updated to show how it could be used to specifically add styles. However, I would reiterate that there are probably more optimal solutions, but this would require clarification on the constraints of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest to you a direct solution for this -

```
let activeIndexes = []
let divs = $($('.active')[0]).parent().find('div') // this will return you an ordered array of divs ( or you can modify a selector to get whatever block you want)
divs.each(function(index, element){
    if ($(element).hasClass('active')) {
        activeIndexes.push(index)
    }
})
```

then you have all active divs and you can do whatever with divs between this two (or other) from the array above ...

```
 for (let i = activeIndexes[0] + 1; i < activeIndexes[1]; i++){
    //todo actions
    console.log(divs[i])
 }
```